# (visible = false) data columns ( Boundfield ->DataField) after button click I want to make visible=true in popup window with copy button

Tags: jquery, popupwindow, aspxgridview

in page load event not visible a grid boundfield, but click the button I want show the Boundfield (DataField="Title", DataField="Notes" ) in popup window

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" SortExpression="Final_Draft" Width="80%">
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField  DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" **Visible="false"** />
                <asp:BoundField  DataField="Final_Draft" HeaderText="Final_Draft" SortExpression="Final_Draft"  />
                <asp:BoundField  DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes"  **Visible="false"**/>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Btn_PopUp" runat="server" Text="PopUp" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

if any one know that possibility please share

Comment: Do you want only to see the values in the popup? or actually turn the colomns to visible=true?

Comment: i want only see in the popup